# Sharepoint 365 doesn't search by content markdown files

Tags: sharepoint, markdown

I have a site in Sharepoint 365 and searches go well on docx, txt, pdfs,etc...

But if I upload a markdown file, I can't search by the content of the file.
Imagine that one line of the content is "Markdown Editor....". If I search "Markdown", it doesn't find any result.

If I do the same with a txt, pdf, docx, ..., it find the document.

Is it not possible to search in markdown files?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/default-crawled-file-name-extensions-and-parsed-file-types), markdown files are no default crawled file name extensions and parsed file formats

Comment: And there is no way to search a markdown files? Installing o using any extension in Sharepoint online?

Comment: You could open a service request to add markdown type as searchable file type.

Comment: And how can I open a service request?  Do I have to contact support?

Comment: Go to SharePoint admin center -> Support -> New service request.